# script.aculo.us Sortable with delimiters

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, scriptaculous, delimiter

I'd like to use Script.aculo.us Sortable to sort elements of a horizontal list (let's say some little boxes). The problem is that these boxes have to be separated from each other by another boxes of a different kind, which shouldn't be movable, but they have to be always there in between these sortable boxes, one between each pair of movable boxes.

Let's mark movable boxes by `[M]` and unmovable delimiters by `[D]`. Then the situation is as follows:

```
[M1][D][M2][D][M3][D][M4]
```

Now, when a user drags, for example, the `[M2]` movable box to the position of `[M4]`, the situation should become as follows:

```
[M1][D][M3][D][M4][D][M2]
```

and when he moves the `[M4]` movable box into the `[M2]` position, the situation should be like below:

```
[M1][D][M3][D][M4][D][M2]
```

But the following settings are forbidden:

```
[M1][D][M3][M4][D][D][M2]
[M1][D][M4][D][M2][M3][D]
```

that is, no two delimiters should be near each other, and no delimiter should be left in front or at the end of the sequence.

How can I make something like that using Script.aculo.us Sortables? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and mark it.

Comment: I moved the answer to separate post. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured a way to make it: It could be done by **CSS rules**.
I simply set the following rule for my list element:

```
li:before {
  content: "[D]";   /* my delimiter */
}

li:first-child:before {
  content: "";
}
```

This makes that all list elements but first will have `[D]` text attached before them in their container.

Now when I move around my list items (`Draggable`s of a `Sortable`), the CSS keeps these delimiters updated: when I drag an element to the beginning of the list, it gains `:fisrt-child` pseudo-class, so it appears without the delimiter. At any other place in the list it lacks this pseudo-class, so the delimiter appears in front of it.

So looks like the problem is solved.